# The usage of the word “straddle”

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Can you explain what the word "straddle" means in the following context please?

Does it mean " pouring mulch/compost in a organized way in long rows like a bale "

> Compost windrow turners were developed to produce compost on a large
>   scale. They are traditionally a large machine that **straddles** a windrow
>   of 4 feet (1.25 meters) or more high, by as much as 12 feet (3.5
>   meters) across. Although smaller machines exist for small windrows,
>   most operations use large machines for volume production.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windrow_composting

Comment: I'm sure it is a more [conventional definition of *straddle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straddle).

Comment: @choster I still don't get it

Comment: @Mrt "to sit or ride with a leg on either side of (something)" or "to be on both sides of (something)" should work. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW3AHpwvKOM) shows such a machine straddling a windrow while turning the windrow at the same time.

Comment: @DamkerngT, Your video is quite helpful. My experience, growing up as a farm boy, was to turn hay with a windrow machine. I was hoping turning mulch is a similar process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary meaning of "straddle" specifically has to do with the positioning of a person's *legs* in relation to something, as in the following pictures.

Straddling a stream (or a tiny river, as explained in the [source](https://www.bpa.gov/Power/pl/columbia/stories/voyage1.htm)):

[image: Straddling a small river]

Straddling a fence (a common metaphor for indecisiveness):

[image: Straddling a fence]

The best way to understand "straddle" is not with a definition that tries to encompass all the many ways the word can be used, but with its primary meaning. People commonly extend the primary meaning metaphorically in an endless variety of ways to create new and different meanings.

It often helps to consider the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=straddle&allowed_in_frame=0) of a word to understand its present meaning. Historically, "straddle" is related to the word "stride". This connection shows itself in the strong association between "straddle" and legs, even though people often use "straddle" to mean things that have nothing to do with literal legs. See also "[straddle stretch](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&tbm=isch&q=straddle+stretch)",
"[straddle cuddle](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&tbm=isch&q=straddle+cuddle)", and especially "[straddle option](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&tbm=isch&q=straddle+option)".

So, even though I have no idea what a compost windrow turner is, my experience as a native speaker leads me to guess from the paragraph that you quoted that it probably has something analogous to a person's legs, and that these "legs" stand at various places around the perimeter of a windrow, with the "body" of the turner above the center of the windrow. (I don't even know what a windrow is.)

---

<sub>The pictures are from: "[Straddle the Columbia](https://www.bpa.gov/Power/pl/columbia/stories/voyage1.htm)" by the Bonneville Power Association, and [Gravity's Rainbow](http://sarcozona.org/2011/06/23/where-are-the-other-queer-ecologists/).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/straddle) defines straddle as *to be on both sides of; extend over or across*. The wheels of the windrow turner would be on both sides of the compost windrow. The mulch has already been poured onto the field before it gets turned. The reason for turning a compost windrow is to face the moist base of the mulch to the top, so the compost dries in the sun with uniform moisture throughout.

Comment: Thanks I see , then straddling a composit is kind of creating rows of piled of compost/mulch before it gets turned which I know why it is done and no need to be done on both side of a field ?

Comment: Not exactly. The rows get created, first, before the windrow machine is used.  After the top has dried to the desired moisture level, the machine turns the moist mulch at the base to the top to dry.

Comment: Well I meant the same thing actually

Comment: @Mrt- *straddling* has only to do with how something is standing or is situated.  It has nothing to do with creating anything.  If I stand with one foot on one side of a puddle and the other foot on the other side of the puddle I am straddling the puddle.  If I place a chair such that two legs are on one side of a crack in the floor and the other two legs are on the other side of the crack then the chair is straddling the crack.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your comment. I knew the definition you mentioned before I asked this question ie we straddle on a bicycle or horse but this definition could not help me with this context. When I say " to creat" I meant " to give a shape" .

Comment: Ok But now you understand how it ***is*** applicable. Right?

Comment: @Mrt - "Straddle" has nothing to do with making rows or anything else. It only means that the machine is supported (in this case by tires) on each side of the row. Whether the machine creates rows, buries rows, sits perfectly still and does nothing, or throws them on a truck is completely unrelated.